# Google Maps JavaScript API Will Not Load Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Federation of Master Landscapers</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyD0X4v7eqMFcWCR-VZAJwEMfb47id9IZao">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function () {

            //draw a map centered at Empire State Building Newyork
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.748492, -73.985496);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
                //Convert Address Into LatLng and Retrieve Address Near by
                convertAddressToLatLng($("#txtAddress").val());
            });
    });               

    function convertAddressToLatLng(address){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //Empty div before re-populating
                $("#divStores").html('');
                searchStores(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                $("#divStores").html(getEmbedHTML('No Stores Found','',''));
            }
        });
    }

    function searchStores(location){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(),location.lng());
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    

        //Marker at the address typed in
        var image = 'images/townhouse.png'
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image
        });     

        //hard coded the radius to 10 miles, if you get the value from a field if required
        var parameters = 'lat='+ location.lat() + '&lng=' + location.lng() + '&radius=25';  

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "store_locator.php",  
            data: parameters,  
            success: function(msg) {  
                //alert(msg);
                displayStores(msg);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }    
        });  /* $.ajax({  */
    }

    function displayStores(result){
        if (result.length > 0){
            for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                //Append Store Address on Sidebar
                var html = getEmbedHTML(i+1,result[i].name,result[i].address,result[i].distance);
                $("#divStores").append(html);
                //place a marker
                var image = 'images/number_' + parseInt(i+1) + '.png';
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image
                }); 

                var msg = 'Location : ' + result[i].name + '<br/> ';
                msg = msg + 'Address : ' + result[i].address + '<br/> ';
                attachMessage(marker, msg);
            }
        } else {
            $("#divStores").html(getEmbedHTML('No Stores Found','',''));
        }
    }

    function attachMessage(marker, msg) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: msg,
            size: new google.maps.Size(120, 150)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function getEmbedHTML(seqno,name,address,distance) {
        var strhtml = '<div class="row">';
        strhtml  =  strhtml + '<img src="images/number_' + seqno + '.png" border="0" width="24" height="24" style="padding-right:10px;" /><label>' + name + '</label><br/>'
        strhtml  =  strhtml + '<span>' + address + '</span><br/>'
        strhtml  =  strhtml + '<span> Distance : ' + parseFloat(distance).toFixed(2) + ' miles</span><br/>'
        strhtml  =  strhtml + '</div>';

        return strhtml;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include ('./template/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="news">
                <h2>Landscaper Map Results</h2>
                <div id="map_canvas"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <h2>Find a Landscaper</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Enter Address:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtAddress" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Distance:</td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="radius" id="radius">
                            <option value="15">15 Miles</option>
                            <option value="25">25 Miles</option>
                            <option value="50">50 Miles</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br /><br />
                <h2>Landscapers</h2>
                <div id="divStores">
                <!--
                <div class="row">
                    <label>Store 1<label><br/>
                    <span> Address Here<span>
                </div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                -->         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include ('./template/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

My code shown above. The script is fetching the results from database and displaying in the list format. But on Page Load or submission of the form the map is not being displayed. I have puzzled for a couple of hours and not a master of javascript I have now came here to ask the question.

Thanks,

Liam.

Comment: Assign a width/height to your map.

Comment: Tried this already, it already has is set in the style.css and also I tried manually setting it to the DIV Tag for example <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>

Comment: Try fixed px for fun... are you getting a js error ?

Comment: I have stripped your code down to the bare essentials to show map and there are no errors(map shows). As you state as you are not conversant with javascript you start with basic map and build on additions incrementally.If errors develop use debugging tool in browser.

Comment: I just took your code and created a fiddle... works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/RdGps/  if you add the style.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for not trying this mysql but after looking over your suggestion @Nix it works when you set exact pixels but not the percentage of 100%. Thank you so much all your help it is greatly appreciated. I think I should give me head a bit of a wobble.